# Which will provide more Stardust: one 10KM egg or five 2KM eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

*In regards to which Pokemon are hatched, a 10KM egg will provide rarer and better Pokemon than a 2km egg. Disregarding the Pokemon that are hatched, I am more interested in the Stardust provided.*

After visiting a couple of Pokestops, I harvested one 10KM egg and five 2KM eggs. In a world with having only one incubator, five 2KM eggs will take equally *(hypothetically)* as long to hatch as a 10KM egg

When I walk the first 10KM, would I receive more Stardust from the one 10KM egg or the five 2KM egg?

Comment: I don't know [if this is reliable](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4uj86o/will_we_have_enough_stardust_to_reach_max_level/d5qpasw) : "Hatch those eggs (2km eggs give around 1k stardust or less, 5km eggs around 1500 or less, and 10km eggs around 2-3k. So don't scoff at those 2k eggs"

Comment: Olivier's link and comment suggest that 2km eggs could give way more stardust/km than 10km eggs, but the ranges are too wide to confirm that. A streak of unlucky 2km eggs vs a high payout from a 10km egg would make the 10km egg better.

Comment: @Kadima but when doing the analysis, you only need to care about the average. They're not asking what the chances are, but if one technique will be better than the other. A technique that is, on average, better will be the better option in a risk-reward analysis. THEREFORE, it would seem that 2k eggs are the best stardust.

Comment: This question doesn't really address the inventory situation too much. Do you have five 2k eggs? Does it matter? You can't drop the 10k egg or the 2k eggs, so you have to hatch them eventually. I made a quick answer that focuses more upon how to prioritize which egg to hatch, which a mention for your stardust issue. Hope it helps and makes sense.

Comment: @ChronoD I'm not too terrible worried on inventory, as yes they will all be hatched eventually :) I was asking in a more generalized term. I will read through you answer here shortly

Comment: @Wondercricket I that case, just hatch the 2k's first. I haven't done too much in terms of data recording, but I noticed on my own that they seem to have better stardust returns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Skip to the last paragraph for a tl;dr.

---

I don't have specific numbers, but Olivier mentioned a source that states the following:

> Hatch those eggs (2km eggs give around 1k stardust or less, 5km eggs around 1500 or less, and 10km eggs around 2-3k. So don't scoff at those 2k eggs

So long as these are relatively accurate, that means you have the following ratios:

1. 2k eggs: up to 500 dust per km
2. 5k eggs: up to 300 dust per km
3. 10k eggs: up to 300 dust per km

Which would suggest that 2k eggs are the best, so long as you are able to keep one hatching.

Now there are a few other things to consider.

When using a 3-use incubator,the limiting factor in this scenario is number of eggs instead of distance, so the criteria for measuring effectiveness changes. You could put three 2k eggs and get up to 3k stardust... or three 10k and get up to 9k stardust. In this instance, putting longer distance eggs would be optimal.

Another factor to consider is your inventory space. In general, it shouldn't matter except in extreme planning scenariors. You can only carry 9 eggs. If you have 9 eggs already, you lose out on gathering more eggs. If you are going to be walking around a and hitting pokestops, you'll want to open up space, so you should hatch the lower distance eggs first.
If you only have 3 eggs, then a higher distance egg wouldn't be an issue since new eggs have spaces to go into.

Lastly, there's also the factor of the hatched pokemon's strength. I read somewhere that the pokemon in the egg (both the breed and the strength) is determined when you first acquire the egg. [I don't remember and can't find the source. Sorry.] So if you grab an egg while level 5 and don't hatch it until you're level 10, it's probably going to be pretty weak. So if you have just used a lucky egg to level up a lot and received an egg, you may want to hatch that first since it is more to be stronger.

---

But overall, I have come to the following conclusions. **It doesn't really matter what you hatch and in what order, so long as you keep hatching.**
Of course there are exceptions if you have a specific short-term goal in mind, but besides that, who cares? You just hatch whatever you need the most at the time, and you'll have to hatch them all eventually!

Here is my priority list for deciding:

- Put 10k's into 3-use incubators if you have them (5k's too if you need space).
- If you need a strong pokemon: Hatch the newest 5k or 10k egg you've gotten
- If you want stardust: Hatch all your 2k eggs
- If you're going to stops for more gear: Hatch all your 2k eggs
- If you're going around gym stomping: Hatch your 10k eggs

This optimizes your egg inventory. Until they allow dropping of eggs, the decision should just be about what your next goal is.

Comment: You mention hatching older/newer eggs a few times. Is there a clear way to tell which eggs are new or old? I've seen "new" 2km eggs get thrown into the middle of my egg list, so how to tell this is not clear to me. If it's not obvious (it's not obvious to me, anyway), I can pose this is an actual question.

Comment: @Ellesedil I have actually not figured out how to tell myself. I tend to hatch all my 2ks immediately and hoard my 5ks for the purpose of hatching multiple with a lucky egg at the same time. So I just know my newest ones are the 2k's and 10k's. Posing it as a question sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score -5):

None, you don't get stardust from hatching eggs.

Comment: This is completely false.